# Can't verify TOR package

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I run Ubuntu 16.04LTS and I'm trying to reinstall TOR because it stopped working...

Right now I'm trying to verify TOR package I downloaded and I'm having problems with the verification.  When I enter this command

> gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290

I get this response

> gpg: requesting key 0x4E2C6E8793298290 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net  
>   ?: invalid HTTP proxy (socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050): unsupported URI  
>   gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
>   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
>   gpg: Total number processed: 0
>   gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
>   gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
>   gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found

What to do?

Comment: Looks like you've misconfigured GnuPG, trying to give it a SOCKS proxy when it expects an HTTP proxy.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks, but I'm a newbie at Linux and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Given that that configuration isn't default on ubuntu I can only assume it's a configuration change you've made yourself.

Comment: I didn't consciously do that.  The only thing I often do is update my Tor & system software via Software Updater.
So since I'm not even sure I know what an http proxy is, I can only guess that this might work (from my reading):  
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --keyserver-options http-proxy=socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050 --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290

Comment: I tried the command  gpg --keyserver-options http-proxy=socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050,debug,verbose --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290

Comment: result:  <br/> gpg: requesting key 0x4E2C6E8793298290 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpgkeys: curl version = GnuPG curl-shim
* HTTP proxy is "socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050"
* HTTP URL is "http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0x4E2C6E8793298290"
* HTTP auth is "null"
* HTTP method is GET
?: invalid HTTP proxy (socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050): unsupported URI

Comment: gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found

Comment: Well what I decided to do was just run the TOR Browser download without the verification.
Not strictly proper but if I can't verify then I can't.

Comment: `http-proxy=socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050` <- Tor isn't an HTTP proxy, modern versions of gnupg support `use-tor` in the config file for its `dirmngr` or `--use-tor` from the command line but it seems like you've tried to get GnuPG to use tor in some method it doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

These are the instructions from the official [Tor Browser User Manual](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/) in case the Ubuntu torbrowser-launcher package hasn't updated the gpg key that is required to install Tor Browser. When I updated the Tor Browser Developers signing key I noticed that the key that I updated will expire in less than one year.

#### Install Tor Browser

1. Navigate to the Tor Browser [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download).
2. Download the GNU/Linux .tar.xz file
3. (Recommended) Verify the file's signature. The steps for verifying the file's signature are shown below.
4. When the download is complete, extract the archive with the command `tar -xf [TB archive]` or with the Archive Manager.
5. Navigate to the newly extracted Tor Browser directory. Right-click on *start-tor-browser*, open *Properties* and change the permission to *Allow executing file as program* by clicking the checkbox.
6. Start Tor Browser from the command line by running:

   ```
   ./start-tor-browser
   ```

---

#### Set a keyboard shortcut to start Tor Browser

Remember the location where you downloaded the tor-browser-linux64-xx.x.xx_xx-xx.tar.xz archive. In this example I will call this location `/home/your-username/Downloads/` which is the default location of the Downloads directory in Ubuntu if you replace `your-username` by your own user name.

Remember the directory where you extracted the Tor Browser files. In this example I will call this directory `/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/` where en is the abbreviation for the language and US is the abbreviation for the nation which could be different depending on your language and nation.

Go to Settings -> *Keyboard* -> *View and Customize Shortcuts* -> *Set Custom Shortcut*.

- In the field after Name type *Tor Browser*.
- In the field after Command type: `sh -c '"/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/your-username/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k`
- In order to fill in an entry in the field after Shortcut press any easy to remember keyboard shortcut combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd>).

[image]

Now you can start Tor Browser by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd>.

---

#### How to verify Tor Browser's signature

**Fetching the Tor Developers key**

The Tor Browser team signs Tor Browser releases. Import the Tor Browser Developers signing key (0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290):

```
gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
```

This should show you something like:

```
gpg: key 4E2C6E8793298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
pub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [C] [expires: 2020-08-24]
      EF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
uid           [ unknown] Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>
sub   rsa4096 2018-05-26 [S] [expires: 2020-09-12]
```

After importing the key, you can save it to a file (identifying it by fingerprint here):

```
gpg --output ./tor.keyring --export 0xEF6E286DDA85EA2A4BA7DE684E2C6E8793298290
```

**Verifying the signature**

To verify the signature of the package you downloaded, you will need to download the corresponding ".asc" signature file as well as the installer file itself, and verify it with a command that asks GnuPG to verify the file that you downloaded.

The example below assumes that you downloaded these two files to your Downloads folder.

```
gpgv --keyring ./tor.keyring ~/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-9.0_en-US.tar.xz{.asc,}
```

The result of the command should produce something like this:

```
gpgv: Signature made 07/08/19 04:03:49 Pacific Daylight Time
gpgv:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpgv: Good signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did what you said but though I tried it a few ways, gedit opened nothing.
Fortunately TOR version 7.5 doesn't need to be installed so I can run it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm OK now.  Tor Browser version 7.5 runs easily on my system without installation just by unpacking it and running the launching file.  In contrast Tor re-installation through Ubuntu Software I couldn't get to work no matter how I uninstalled/reinstalled or what special commands I used.  I don't mind running it directly.  In fact that might be better, because I verified the signature of the Tor download I unzipped, but I never verified the Ubuntu Software one.

Comment: I fully understand that because in the beginning I downloaded Tor Browser from the official Tor website and ran it directly too, but that lasted only about 24 hours because I don't give up easy. I searched the internet and found nothing, so I had to figure it out for myself, because I reasoned that it must be a bug and I wanted to put the bug fix online to share it with everyone who is affected by the same bug. If you look at my profile you will see that I registered for Tor Q&A only 9 days ago, and the reason why I registered here was to share this solution.

Comment: Dear karel: I appreciate your help but I hope you are not implying that I "give up" more "easily" than you.  Our purposes are different.  To run it directly actually serves my purposes better than installation (I realize now, for a couple of reasons I don't need to get into).
And BTW it still works fine thank God.

Comment: I think the way you're doing it also automatically updates itself like mine. I don't know because I haven't checked yet, but I have both Tor Browsers installed, so I'll find out soon enough. If so the advantages of using the Ubuntu repo package are that it launches the usual way from the Dash (see the screenshot in my answer) and it survives a distribution upgrade the same way.

Comment: OK I'll say a little more.  I'm tired of using TOR on the dash, because it exposes that I use TOR to anyone who sees my screen, and I'm tired of it just stopping to work sometimes, and I never get to verify the package signature.  Recently from the launcher I would click TOR, it would seem to load, then it would stop loading. No error message.  Before this, maybe a year ago, it refused to load but gave an error message: that's where the fix with updating the keys worked.  I admit I may have a problem with my gnupg configuration which apparently is not default to Ubuntu's SOCKS proxy. I dunno.

Comment: Maybe I'll start another threat about how to fix my gnupg

Comment: "Recently from the launcher I would click TOR, it would seem to load, then it would stop loading. No error message." That's **exactly the same error** that I got in Ubuntu 16.04 and that I fixed in my answer. I guarantee that it works.

Comment: This answer is for `torbrowser-launcher`, which is a python script that downloads and verifies Tor Browser (specifically, its to fix this bug: https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/313). It's not how OP is trying to install Tor Browser.

Comment: @cacahuatl No, you're confused. What really happened is that the OP installed Tor Browser from the Ubuntu Software app and when it stopped working his solution was to download Tor Browser  and install it manually. Unhappy for me because as far as I know right know I'm the only person in the world who figured out how to solve that very same problem and the thanks I got for it is to be publicly pilloried as a stupid person. If the same solution came from the pen of a moderator it would get more respect. Usually a stream of comments under an answer means that the OP is condemning the answer.

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en  weird that the command they're having issues with is exactly the one for the manual install process and `torbrowser-launcher` creates it's own gnupg config file in a different folder and their solution was *not* to edit the Tor Browser launcher one. I must be the confused one and that's why your answer is accepted and the user didn't fix it themself.

Comment: It's an X-Y problem. The OP's Tor Browser stopped working so he decided to throw it out and install it manually and it barfed up his obsolete gpg key. So I told him to update it. I've done all these thing myself, I'm not throwing links at anybody. My suggestion was to solve the underlying problem, but I'm like Cassandra given the gift of true prophecy, but cursed by the Gods to be disbelieved by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't a proper answer, but realizing I had another laptop with Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and realizing from cacauati that by main laptop's configuration was abnormal, and not knowing how to make it normal, instead I was able to complete the TOR package verification easily by copying the files to the other laptop and running the standard TOR-website commands there.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other newbie users here, and as a more proper answer, I found that all I needed to do to restore keyserver download function (the step before verifing the TOR package) was to open /home/.gnupg/gpg.conf with a text editor, find the line

> keyserver-options http-proxy=socks5-hostname://127.0.0.1:9050

and put a # in front of it to de-activate it.